# escaping comment inside comment in CPP

Tags: c++, escaping, comments

I have a CPP Code with doxygen documentation.
In the documentation  need to put a comment path something like

**/path/to/folder/asd*/new/foo.txt**

what happens is the "*/" ends the comment in CPP abruptly....leave alone doxygen.
Is there a way to escape it?

Comment: Use one-line comments (`//`)

Comment: No doubt it will work, hoping for a better solution